# Can beamforming be created by transmitting same signal with different phase

Tags: beamforming, mimo

As known, the basic idea of beamforming is to transmit the same signal using more transmit antennas, let's say we have $4$ transmit; leading to increase the power of the transmitted signal as well as focus its direction .

My question, what's about if we transmit the same signal but with different phase, for example instead of transmitting $X = [x;x;x;x]$ the new signal becomes $X = [x; -x; x; -x]$. Will the beamforming advantages will be kept and why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can beamforming be created by transmitting same signal with different phase

Yes, that's literally how you do beamforming, usually. It's called "phased array", if your geometric arrangement of antennas can be called an "array".

You might write down the formula which you use to describe your understanding of beamforming, and you'll see the phase terms in that.

> Will the beamforming advantages will be kept and why ?

We don't know exactly what kind of advantages you're thinking of, but since that's exactly what most beamformers do, yes?

Again, write down your formula for a beamformer. Then, look for the terms that change your signal's phase.

Comment: Could you please provide me a reference document where I can read about its basic?

Comment: well, where did you read about "beamforming"? It seems like you have these basics, you just need to actually work with the formulas you've got!

Comment: @Gze as I don't know your background, I would recommend https://web.stanford.edu/~dntse/Chapters_PDF/Fundamentals_Wireless_Communication_chapter7.pdf for intermediate levels.

Answer (score 1):

Beamforming is a spatial diversity and as such requires physical space between the transmitting elements. As long as the same signal is transmitted from a different spatial location, then beam forming can be accomplished by changing the phase of the signal to each antenna.

With a single antenna you can get time diversity with the same approach of changing the phase of multiple copies and combined out of a single antenna, but not spatial diversity.

Comment: Could you please provide me a reference document where I can read about it?

Comment: I would just end up googling it where I think you will find plenty of info